# Visual Studio 2015 suddenly started displaying my plaintext HTML

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm going through the Lynda.com ASP.NET MVC 5 Essentials course, when out of nowhere, I start getting plain HTML appearing when I try to view my site. I've tried different browsers with no luck. Any idea what could cause this?

EDIT: I should note, I'm not getting any errors at all.

I'll throw up some of my code, but I'm not 100% sure which pieces are relevant.

index.cshtml:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 margin-top-20">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-down">Withdrawal
        </span>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print">
            Print Statement
        </span>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-transfer">
            Withdrawal
        </span>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-up">
            Deposit
        </span>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 margin-top-20"></div>
```

}

HomeController.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace AutomatedTellerMachine.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
            {
            return View();
        }

        [ActionName("about-this-atm")]
        public ActionResult About()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.TheMessage = "Having trouble? Send us a message!";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Foo()
        {
            return View("About");
        }

        public ActionResult Serial(string letterCase)
        {
            var serial = "ASPNETMVC5ATM1";
            if (letterCase == "lower")
            {
                return Content(serial.ToLower());
            }

            return Json(new { name = "serial", ValueProvider = serial }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Contact(string message)
        {
            // TODO : send message to HQ
            ViewBag.Message = "Thanks, we got your message!";

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Layout.cshtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - MVC Bank</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("MVC Bank", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
                @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - MVC Bank - @Html.Action("Serial", "Home")</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

And this is what I see in my browser:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Home Page - MVC Bank</title>
    <link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">MVC Bank</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Home/About">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Home/Contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="/Account/Register" id="registerLink">Register</a></li>
        <li><a href="/Account/Login" id="loginLink">Log in</a></li>
    </ul>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">




<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 margin-top-20">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-down">Withdrawal
        </span>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print">
            Print Statement
        </span>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-transfer">
            Withdrawal
        </span>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-up">
            Deposit
        </span>
    </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 margin-top-20"></div>
</div>

}
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; 2016 - MVC Bank - {"name":"serial","ValueProvider":"ASPNETMVC5ATM1"}</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/respond.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Some code would help. Also, any errors in the browser's console or VS output window.

Comment: Just made the edit. Not sure why I didn't do that in the first place. As I mention above, I'm not getting any errors either in VS or my browser.

Comment: What does the output look like? Does it at least render the Razor values from the server?

Comment: Yes, it does render the razor values. I'll edit to show what I'm seeing when I hit 'go'

Comment: You have a random close bracket at the end of `index.cshtml`. Although, I doubt that's the problem...

Comment: Haha, thanks for the catch. Unfortunately, that was indeed not the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108358/discussion-between-tah-tatsumoto-and-jemtan990).